# How to convert image from automatic Selenium to Base 64?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I want to convert an image to Base64. I test a website and an image URL expires after 3s and change after 3s and reload auto in the page? Is there a way to take it from the locally loaded copy as base64 string?

I use Javascript, I [take a look 1 article](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:x-X285hepOEJ:brantleytec.blogspot.com/2013/02/webdriver-screen-shot-in-c.html%20&cd=3&hl=et&ct=clnk&gl=ee&client=firefox-a) like but it's write with C#.
I want convert it to Javascript.

I do not know if there is an alternative solution.

Can you suggest other solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
var image = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.Id('id of image tag'));
```

after this, you can get the `src` attribute

```
image.getAttribute('src').then(function(src) {
   //download the image using the driver and store it
});
```

wait 3 seconds using `driver.wait`

```
driver.wait(function() {
  //load the image again and compare
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want convert image to base64 because this image will auto change after 3s. Your answer save src image but after 3s it do not appear.

Comment: Can your explain me where are src in? How to call it? Thank you.